# Change model after binding

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

I have a bound a model to an element, like this:

```
var el = rivets.bind($('#game'), { game: games[0] });
```

Later, I want to use `games[1]` as the model instead of `games[0]`. I have tried:

```
el.unbind();
var el = rivets.bind($('#game'), { game: games[1] });
```

but it does not appear to work. Unbinding stops the view from updating, but the new model does not take its place. Both models have the same object type. What's going on?

Comment: I see that if I re-instantiate the template between unbind the (re)bind, something like `$("#game").html("{game.attribute}")` it works. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Even I did the same when i need to rebind another model